# Rxjs. Map each object Observable<Foo[]> using http call

Tags: dictionary, rxjs, observable

Let's say, I have an endpoint which return `Foo[]`. Here is simpliest `Foo` class:

```
class Foo{
booId: number;
someProperty: string;
}
```

And what I want to do, is call another Http request for each `Foo` object to fetch `Boo` object with `booId`, then merge those two objects into one and return object which looks like that:

```
class FooWithBoo{
boo: Boo;
someProperty: string;
}
```

I know there is a lot of `Rxjs operators` which I can propably use but there is too many of them and I  don't know which should i use. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will be written like :

```js
http.get(/*url to get Foo[]*/)
 .pipe(
   mergeMap(fooArray => from(fooArray)), //flatMap the returned array
   concatMap(foo => http.get(/*url to get Boo*/ + foo.booId))
 )
 .subscribe()
```

Comment: It was almost what I needed, however I had to add `toArray` and It worked. Thanks :D

Comment: you wellcome :) why you need `toArray` ?

Comment: Actually, I had kinda more complicated case. I am using `Ngrx` and I have form, where I have `FormArray` (I can add new object to `FormArray`) and couple of `FormControl` objects. However, some of those objects could be created earlier (they have `id`) and you can add another objects (they don't have `id`). So before I save the `FormGroup#value` in store, I needed to iterate through the Array and for each object without `id` generate it on backend, then I needed to merge this array (with objects id) with rest of `Form`. I ended up using`forkJoin` to merge those 2 parts of `Form`.